# Does phased array antenna beam rotates 360 degrees?

Tags: antenna

I wonder what happens when the beam shifted. I mean, is it being blinded for a while at first direction (i.e 0 degree) when it goes to second direction (i.e 45 degree)? Or it complete the whole cycle so quickly to not fail?

Comment: Hi Burak, not quite sure what kind of phased array you're thinking about; some can adjust the phases of the individual antenna elements smoothly and would allow you to gradually shift the beam, others will simply switch from one setting to another, and then the switchover would be instantaneous (or, as instantaneous as the phase shifting works). that's certainly up for a system designer to specify, so no general answer can be given.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hi Marcus, I actually meant gradually shifting. When it exactly pointed at 45 degree (assuming no beam at 0 degree at that moment), does the antenna beam quickly come back to 0 degree by completing 360 degree, Is that why DSPs or FPGAs used for this quick cycle completing?

Comment: as said, that completely depends on the actual system you're looking at, and a general answer can't be given.